# java JTable, defaultTableModel want addRow

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to add row to JTable like this

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            try {
                Builder builder = new Builder();
                Document doc = builder.build(Config.PATH +"incasation.xml");

                Element root = doc.getRootElement();    
                Elements childs = root.getChildElements("locations");

                model.addColumn("Name");
                model.addColumn("Total");
                model.addColumn("Location fee");
                model.addColumn("Bank");
                model.addColumn("Tax");

                float baseSum = 0;
                float locationSum = 0;
                float bankSum = 0;
                float taxSum = 0;

                for(int i=0; i< childs.size(); i++)
                {
                    Element child = childs.get(i);

                    model.addRow(new Object[] {
                        child.getFirstChildElement("name").getValue(),
                        child.getFirstChildElement("base").getValue(),
                        child.getFirstChildElement("locationfee").getValue(),
                        child.getFirstChildElement("bank").getValue(),
                        child.getFirstChildElement("tax").getValue()
                    });


                    baseSum += Float.parseFloat(child.getFirstChildElement("base").getValue());

                    locationSum += Float.parseFloat(child.getFirstChildElement("locationfee").getValue());
                    bankSum += Float.parseFloat(child.getFirstChildElement("bank").getValue());
                    taxSum += Float.parseFloat(child.getFirstChildElement("tax").getValue());

                }


                model.addRow(new Object[] {
                    "SUM",
                    Float.toString(baseSum),
                    Float.toString(locationSum),
                    Float.toString(bankSum),
                    Float.toString(taxSum)
                });

            }
            catch(Exception e){}
```

and in that case it JTable gets only first row, so I tryied like this

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            try {
                Builder builder = new Builder();
                Document doc = builder.build(Config.PATH +"incasation.xml");

                Element root = doc.getRootElement();    
                Elements childs = root.getChildElements("locations");

                model.addColumn("Name");
                model.addColumn("Total");
                model.addColumn("Location fee");
                model.addColumn("Bank");
                model.addColumn("Tax");

                float baseSum = 0;
                float locationSum = 0;
                float bankSum = 0;
                float taxSum = 0;

                for(int i=0; i< childs.size(); i++)
                {
                    Element child = childs.get(i);

                    model.addRow(new Object[] {
                        child.getFirstChildElement("name").getValue(),
                        child.getFirstChildElement("base").getValue(),
                        child.getFirstChildElement("locationfee").getValue(),
                        child.getFirstChildElement("bank").getValue(),
                        child.getFirstChildElement("tax").getValue()
                    });

                }

                for(int j=0; j< childs.size(); j++)
                {
                    Element child = childs.get(j);

                    baseSum += Float.parseFloat(child.getFirstChildElement("base").getValue());         
                    locationSum += Float.parseFloat(child.getFirstChildElement("locationfee").getValue());
                    bankSum += Float.parseFloat(child.getFirstChildElement("bank").getValue());
                    taxSum += Float.parseFloat(child.getFirstChildElement("tax").getValue());
                }

                model.addRow(new Object[] {
                    "SUM",
                    Float.toString(baseSum),
                    Float.toString(locationSum),
                    Float.toString(bankSum),
                    Float.toString(taxSum)
                });

            }
            catch(Exception e){}
```

I this case the last row is not added.
How to solve this problem?

**EDIT** 
I found the solution one of the value was empty string thats why there was no sum.
It should be like

```
String base = child.getFirstChildElement("base").getValue();
baseSum += Float.parseFloat(base.equals("") ? "0" : base);
```

Comment: The example should be adding one row per child plus a Sum row.  Is it not adding the last child or the sum?  Do you have a SSCCE?

Comment: In secound example the SUM is not added, in first just first row is added childs.size() is 7 but on screen is just one row

Comment: What did you change between the two pieces of code?

Comment: @jzd what do you mean ?? i have give the anwser ?? should I change all code ?

Comment: You must have edited the question when I was commenting.  Anyway, I was asking what the difference was between the two big pieces of code.  What did you change?

Comment: In secound example the sum is moved too other loop

Answer (score 2):

You have edited the question with a solution.  However, the solution was not obvious because an exception was thrown that was caught and disregarded.

This is a great example of why this line of code can be problematic:

```
catch(Exception e){}
```

I would suggest to at least do a `e.printStackTrace()`, so that worse case debugging would be easier.